# Draw multiple polygons(buildings, borders) in a single draw call using gl.drawLines on a map using WebGL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, webgl, polygon

I am using WebGL to draw polygons on a canvas layer on top of my map for OSM data. I am first plotting the coordinate points for each polygon and trying to connect those points using gl.LINES. I have written a query(in PHP) that returns a list of polygons from the planet_osm_polygon table. It returns the list as JSON objects. I am using an index buffer and drawElements to draw the polygons like this:

```
gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, vetexIndex.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

This is my index buffer:

```
pIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pIndexBuffer); 
pVertexIndices = new Uint16Array([0,1, 1,2, 2,3, 3,4, 4,5, 5,6, 6,7, 7,8]);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pVertexIndices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Every time I try to draw the polygons in a single draw call, only the last polygon in my OSM table is rendered/drawn. The other polygons are never drawn, though the points/coordinates for them are being passed correctly from the PHP-land to the WebGL-land(I tried to print the points). I am using scaling as such:

```
function scaleMatrix(matrix, scaleX, scaleY) {
  matrix[0] *= scaleX;
  .....
  matrix[3] *= scaleX;
  matrix[4] *= scaleY;
  .....
  matrix[7] *= scaleY;
}
```

And my translation is

```
function translateMatrix(matrix, tx, ty) {

   matrix[12] += matrix[0]*tx + matrix[4]*ty;
   matrix[13] += matrix[1]*tx + matrix[5]*ty;
   .....
   matrix[15] += matrix[3]*tx + matrix[7]*ty;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Edit -- My PhP query/code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way,4326))
      FROM planet_osm_polygon
      WHERE highway IS NOT NULL
      AND ST_Intersects(way, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope((-122.302571660907),
        (37.5601802504715), (-122.436330806712),
          (37.8074531813721), 94326), 900913))";

.....
$points_collection = array();
 while($data=pg_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {

    $st_astext = $data["st_astext"];
    .....
    $points = array();
    foreach($locations as $location) {
      $tmp = explode(" ", $location);
      array_push($points ,array("lon"=>(float) $tmp[0], "lat"=> (float) $tmp[1]));
    }
    array_push($points_collection, $points);
}
```

So now, this returns the lat-long points for each place (each row) in the DB. This is passed to the WebGL-land.

In WebGL,I have the usual shaders and compile shader functions, as in this link: 
http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2013/02/displaying-webgl-data-on-google-maps.html

All of the functions used are pretty much the same as in the above link. I have only added the extra index buffer (see above) and have modified the drawArrays() to a drawElements() function. Now I need to draw many polygons with a single draw call; always the last one only is getting drawn.

Comment: I think you need to post more code. There's nothing obvious from what you posted. Do you get any errors? Does the [WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/) help? It tries to visualize your data. Since you're only drawing lines you could also try [doing it manually using the 2D canvas](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/3d-in-canvas.html) as a way to try to debug.

Comment: The Javascript console in google chrome helped me to identify that the lat-long points are passed to WebGL,but are still not being drawn.